# CSV league not skipping empty records

Tags: php, thephpleague

I am using PHPleague to parse csv and insert it to the database. https://csv.thephpleague.com/

And I have code as follows:

```
$csv = Reader::createFromPath($path, 'r');
$csv->skipEmptyRecords();

$csv->setHeaderOffset(0);
$csv_header = $csv->getHeader();

$stmt = (new Statement())
    ->offset('0')
    ->limit('20')
;

$records = $stmt->process($csv);
foreach($records as $record){
    print_r($record); // this show that it has processed empty records as well
}
exit();
```

I could trim the empty records myself as well as by calling following function as `$records = $this->trimArray($records);`

```
    public function trimArray($arr)
    {
        $final = array();

        foreach($arr as $k => $v)
        {
            if(array_filter($v)) {
                $final[] = $v;
            }
        }

        return $final;

    }
```

However, I want it to be trimmed before than that. Instead of adding my own layer to filter it is there anyway on csvleague to `skipemptyrecords`. I have tried with `$csv->skipEmptyRecords();` but it is not skipping empty records. Am I doing anything wrong?

My file looks like:
[image]

I want to skip all those empty records.

Comment: Seems like because of `comma` it's not treating them empty records

Answer (score 1):

I had a simple experience with League\CSV and tried to catch the data from a csv file. The package codes depend strongly on the version that you have installed. So at first step check the version of League. I think you should read the League documentation page about stream filters.
https://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/connections/filters/